# PHP TCP socket server hangs when accepting a new connection

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, freeze

I'm trying to set up a TCP socket server, which should support many client connections at the same time, together with receiving and sending data.

For this purpose I'm trying to use PHP's `socket_select();` due to server always hanged on `socket_read();` process, where it should continue, no matter if there were data, or not. I Tried to run following code below, but it always hangs on a new client connection.

```
// TCP socket created
$clients = array($socket);
while (true) { // Infinite loop for server
   $newsock = socket_accept($socket);
   if ($newsock !== false) {
      // Adds a new client
      $clients[] = $newsock;
   }
   $read = $clients;
   $write = NULL;
   $except = NULL;
   $num_changed_sockets = socket_select($read, $write, $except, 0);
   if ($num_changed_sockets === false) {
      // Error here
   } else if ($num_changed_sockets > 0) {
      // Something happened
      if (in_array($socket, $read)) {
         $key = array_search($socket, $read);
         unset($read($key]);
      }
      foreach ($read as $read_socket) {
         $data = socket_read($read_socket, 128); // This should not hang!
         if ($data === false) {
            // Disconnect client
         }
         // Reads data, sends answer...
      }
   }
   // Something to send for all clients
}
```

Is it also possible to use `socket_select();` without having a copy of my clients in an array, where the listener is included? Just having a clean array for clients.

Comment: Do you set the file descriptors [non-blocking](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-set-nonblock.php)?

Comment: Have you tried an strace on the php process?

Comment: Adding a server to non-blocking mode caused me an error last time. Now it executes the code, but the client is not being disconnected. Should I Set non-block mode for clients too?

Answer (score 1):

Sockets are by default *blocking*, you should put the passive listening socket (`$socket` in your case) in the read set passed to `socket_select` as well, and it will be readable when you can accept new connections.

Comment: `$socket` must be included in `$read` in order to make the `socket_send` work. Otherwise, an error is thrown about socket resources.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the listening socket `$socket` to non-blocking mode. Clients get connected and data is being read, but the client disconnects are not handled in real time (there is a pretty big delay on it). Is there reason for that?